# Type Cast sender (object) as dropdownlist and bind data to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I want to use one function to bind data to multiple RadDropDownList(s) on the same page.

ASPX :

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList OnPreRender="bind_dd"ID="pprice_paymethod" 

ClientIDMode="Static"runat="server" Width="100px" Skin="Metro" DefaultMessage="Pay 

Method"AppendDataBoundItems="true"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

C#

```
protected void bind_dd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    RadDropDownList dd = sender as RadDropDownList;

    dd.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dd.DataValueField = "Payment_Type_ID";
    dd.DataTextField = "Payment_Type";
    dd.DataBind();

}
```

Soultion ?

Comment: This code is binding data to dd but not to sender. I've already tried to : sender = (object)dd; (:
not working...

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Edit your question with your goal don't write comments about it.

Comment: I want to use one function to bind data to multiple RadDropDownList(s) on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

- In this case I have a LookUp table within my database it is set up by CategoryID.
  Fields are as follows

LookUpID int

CategoryID int

Description varchar(20)

Value varchar(10)

LookupGroup int

This is the Call that will call the function

**FillAjaxDropDown(LookUpCategory.Gender, ddlGender, DropDownComboDefault.DefaultValueEmpty)**

I send over the CategoryID of the data that I want in my lookup table in this case Gender

I send the dropdown control - the control I have within my ASP.Net page In this case ddlGender

I send it over how I want the control displayed when it is bound om this case DefaultValueEmpty

**public void FillAjaxDropDown(int iCategoryID, AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox ddl, DropDownComboDefault DefaultValue)
{**

-This is my data access layer it creates a new data access 
        **DAL.DataAccess Dal = new DAL.DataAccess();**

-This creates the data type I will fill my drop down list with
        **dynamic obj = new LookUpCollection();**

-This was the call to the data access which calls the stored procedure and fills my LookupCollection object.
        **obj = Dal.GetLookupByCategoryID(iCategoryID);**

-I check to see if there is an records within the object
        **if (obj.Count > 0) {**

- I make sure that nothing is selected within the dropdown list
          **ddl.SelectedIndex = -1;**
- I set the datasourcce to the object.
          **ddl.DataSource = obj;**
- Set the fields within my object
          **ddl.DataValueField = "Value";
          ddl.DataTextField = "Description";**

-I bind the data object to the dropdown control
            **ddl.DataBind();**

- Depending on the what was sent in for DropDownComboDefault I determine what the default display is if I want the first field to show nothing, an empty string or a string that says -Select-

  ```
      **switch (DefaultValue) {
          case DropDownComboDefault.DefaultValueNone:
              break;
          case DropDownComboDefault.DefaultValueEmpty:
              ddl.Items.Insert(0, "");
              ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
              break;
          case DropDownComboDefault.DefaultValueSelect:
              ddl.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
              ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
              break;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

**Create This function**

public void FillDropDown(dd RadDropDownList)
{

```
dd.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dd.DataValueField = "Payment_Type_ID";
dd.DataTextField = "Payment_Type";
dd.DataBind();
```

}

**--Call the function**

FillDropDown(dd);

-- dd is the name of your dropdown control

Comment: Well I have a separate Dal/DataAccess layer but in your case. I will try to edit it to fit what you have.

Comment: I completely understood what you are doing here. But the problem is when i do onprerender="myfuction" it sends two parameters; Sender (object) and Event e.
What I want to do is recognize he sender and bind data to it.

Comment: Try the bottom code Create your function and then call the function from your code.  You could send any RadDropDownList control to it and it will populate that control with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Solution :

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList OnPreRender="bind_dd" ID="pprice_paymethod" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="100px" Skin="Metro" DefaultMessage="Pay Method" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="BusinessLogic_EnableBillButton"></telerik:RadDropDownList>


protected void bind_dd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    RadDropDownList dd = sender as RadDropDownList;

    dd.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dd.DataValueField = "Payment_Type_ID";
    dd.DataTextField = "Payment_Type";
    dd.DataBind();

}
```